# Change YOCTO Linux kernel version

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am using **yocto project** to build linux os image.
I used SUMO release so I had **4.14.73 kernel version**.

The problem is that i have pre-compiled linux driver which version is **4.14.88**.

I think that i must upgrade my linux kernel to become the same version of the driver.

Any Idea how to do that please ?

Answer (score 4):

1) You have to use **PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto = "4.14.88"** in your distro config, e.g:
http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-yocto/conf/distro/poky.conf?h=daisy#n22

Note however that Sumo does not provide 4.14.88. The latest Sumo I see provides 4.14.76:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.14.bb?h=sumo#n27

So your options are to create a linux-yocto_4.14.bbappend and modify the version, or create a new kernel recipe altogether to fit your needs.

Comment: beware, "linux-yocto" is a default linux kernel name might be different in the actual build tree. look at KERNEL_PROVIDER variable for the actual name used